porting iptables rules to nftables in a Linux Virtual Server direct route context
The context:
I have an old LVS environment that makes an high availability load balaced dns server.
I am trying to reinstall it on computers which run more recent OS, like a Deb 12 where I got the ipvsadm daemon running.
My test environment includes a front-end VM and one, but I will add more, real server(s):
root@dnsfend3:~# ipvsadm -l -n
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  172.17.16.21:53 wlc
  -> 192.168.253.251:53           Route   1      0          0         
UDP  172.17.16.21:53 wlc
  -> 192.168.253.251:53           Route   1      0          0         

The 192.168.253.251 is the real server.
The real server sends back the answers to the client by using the following iptables rules:
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [86840:8357393]
:INPUT ACCEPT [82433:7784675]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [78270:11491991]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [78273:11492087]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 11 11:10:05 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Aug 11 11:10:05 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2558:177414]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2375:155917]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [727:52003]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [727:52003]
-A PREROUTING -d 172.17.16.21/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
-A PREROUTING -d 172.17.16.21/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 11 11:10:05 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Aug 11 11:10:05 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [82430:7784496]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [78267:11491652]
:POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:PREROUTING - [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 11 11:10:05 2015

**This works**, but I would like start using nftables instead.

By using iptables-restore-translate I got:


add table ip mangle
add chain ip mangle PREROUTING { type filter hook prerouting priority -150; policy accept; }
add chain ip mangle INPUT { type filter hook input priority -150; policy accept; }
add chain ip mangle FORWARD { type filter hook forward priority -150; policy accept; }
add chain ip mangle OUTPUT { type route hook output priority -150; policy accept; }
add chain ip mangle POSTROUTING { type filter hook postrouting priority -150; policy accept; }
add table ip nat
add chain ip nat PREROUTING { type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept; }
add chain ip nat INPUT { type nat hook input priority 100; policy accept; }
add chain ip nat OUTPUT { type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept; }
add chain ip nat POSTROUTING { type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept; }
add rule ip nat PREROUTING ip daddr 172.17.16.21 udp dport 53 counter 
add rule ip nat PREROUTING ip daddr 172.17.16.21 tcp dport 53 counter 
add table ip filter
add chain ip filter INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept; }
add chain ip filter FORWARD { type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept; }
add chain ip filter OUTPUT { type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept; }
add chain ip filter POSTROUTING
add chain ip filter PREROUTING


These nftables rules can be loaded without errors by nft -f filename.nft command, but don't work, that is the client never receive the answer, so I suspect that it is not a good translation.
Any help and/or suggestion about this problem?
